# Easiest way to get words of one line from istream into a vector?

Tags: stl, istream, c++

`istream` has the `>>` operator, but it skips new lines like it skips whitespace. How can I get a list of all the words in 1 line only, into a vector (or anything else that's convenient to use)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility (though considerably more verbose than I'd like) is:

```
std::string temp;
std::getline(your_istream, temp);

std::istringstream buffer(temp);
std::vector<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer)),
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

Comment: It does look a verbose. (But hey, I asked for C++.) Why the use `std::copy` instead of Foo Bah's for loop?

Comment: @MTsoul: Mostly because I prefer to use algorithms unless they get completely insane (though I'll admit this borders on it...)

Comment: You don't need `std::copy()`. Use the constructor of `std::vector`.

Comment: @Jerry: In VS2010, line 5 has warning C4930, and the line is left out uncompiled.  I was trying it out for comprehension, and no can do.

Comment: @Michael Smith: Oops -- the most vexing parse strikes again. It should be fixed now...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `getline` to buffer the line into a `string`, then using a `stringstream` to parse the contents of that `string`.  For example:

```
string line;
getline(fileStream, line);

istringstream converter(line);
for (string token; converter >> token; )
    vector.push_back(token);
```

Be wary of using C string reading functions in C++.  The `std::string` I/O functions are much safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call istream::getline -- will read into a character array

For example:

```
char buf[256];
cin.getline(buf, 256);
```

And if you want to use a streams-compatible accessor for the individual tokens in the line, consider an istringstream